# USB-C Power Injector

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, charging, power

I was wondering if a device exists for this yet:

I have a normal screen that currently as an AUKEY HDMI to USB-C running from it to my 2017 MacBook Pro. It works well. I charge the laptop with the adapter provided with the MacBook (a seperate cable):

Is it possible to instead inject the power from the power adapter into the USB-C cable used for screen? That would mean that I only have to plug in one cable. I know that certain limited screens are capable of delivering the the 83W of power required along with the display signal, so I think technically this is possible with an injector but I've not been able to find anything on the market. I'd prefer to be able to inject the power supplied by the Apple power adapter vs some third party device if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all these years later I ended up buying an [LG UltraFine 4K Display](https://www.apple.com/nz/shop/product/HMUA2X/A/lg-ultrafine-4k-display).

It supplies plenty of power to keep my 15" MBP charging plus it has a dock integrated, so my second older screen (just on a HDMI to USB-C Dongle) can daisy chain in. It's single-cable nirvana :D

Answer (score 3):

Any usb-c hub with power delivery should do the job, eg. [Anker Premium USB-C Hub with Power Delivery](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/premium-usb-c-hub-with-power-delivery/A8301041)

Comment: That's close but one with an extra USB-C port would be required to input the screen signal. At least I know what terms to search for :)